# How to edit toDataUrl function in fabric.js?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

My application uses image filters extensively. When I use `json.stringify
(canvas)` function, in the return bject I get the filters used as follows:

```
"filters":[{"type":"Sepia2"},{"type":"ColorMatrix","matrix":[some values]},]
```

Apart from the default details, I want to add some other details about the filter like

```
"filters":[{"type":"Sepia2","isSlider":"Yes","Origin":"userClicked"}]
```

Anyway to include these details?

**Reason:** I store the Json in a file system, so when I read the file,I want those details about the filters too.

Comment: What issue are you having including further details at `JSON`? Where is `.toDataURL()` used?

Comment: This is how I use `canvas.toDataURL({format: 'png',
      multiplier: 3});`, it just fives me he type of image filter, how do I include extra details?

Comment: Can you include resulting `data URI` at Question? Is the string representation of `data URI` `JSON` at Question?

Comment: oh yeah thats json,the return value is Object and I convert it into json using JSON.stringify

Comment: This is probably not the returned object of `toDataURL()` since this method will return a string representing a dataURI version of your canvas **image**. I guess you are using [`toJSON`](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.StaticCanvas.html#toJSON) which has a `propertiesToIncludeopt` parameter.

Comment: @Kaiido: yes you are right,my mistake, `JSON.stringify(canvas)` is the function that I am using, so now how can I include the properties?

Comment: Read fabricjs manual, it will show you how ro set the propertiesToInclude parameter of the toJson method. Here is a fiddle I didn't test, written by someone I don't know : https://www.google.com/url?q=http://jsfiddle.net/Kienz/E7byS/&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjYrczZ-p_OAhVLGJQKHZjnCP0QFggLMAA&usg=AFQjCNE9WfCHln9lDab0ayrehZDOPobvvg

Comment: your suggestion worked..thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the info, so that you can use it when re-rendering the images.

Suggestions:
 1. Try not to alter the fabric object.
 2. Store the extra info in another field beside the filter field, and read that field while rendering the image, and apply those properties to image.